# Issue trying to move a label using insertAfter on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

For some specific condition, I want to move a label element to the top. My solution was very simple:

```js
$("label[for='option_3']").insertAfter("label[for='option_0");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="option_0">
  first item
</label>
<label for="option_1">
  second item
</label>
<label for="option_2">
  third item
</label>
<label for="option_3">
  forth item
</label>
<label for="option_4">
  fifth item
</label>
```

It worked pretty well on Firefox and Chrome, but it didn't work on Safari (Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7)).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with you jQuery statement it should be

```
$("label[for='option_3']").insertAfter("label[for='option_0']");
```

you are missing to close the  '' and [] after option_0. Chrome is intelligent enough to handle this issue by itself but safari is not

```js
$("label[for='option_3']").insertAfter("label[for='option_0']");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="option_0" id="one">
  first item
</label>
<label for="option_1">
  second item
</label>
<label for="option_2">
  third item
</label>
<label for="option_3">
  forth item
</label>
<label for="option_4">
  fifth item
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you @Deep. (Chrome and Firefox worked even with the mistype, that tricked me)

Answer (score 0):

$("label[for='option_3']").insertAfter("label[for='option_0']");

rectify your jquery, then it will work perfectly on safari too.

```js
$("label[for='option_3']").insertAfter("label[for='option_0']");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="option_0">
  first item
</label>
<label for="option_1">
  second item
</label>
<label for="option_2">
  third item
</label>
<label for="option_3">
  forth item
</label>
<label for="option_4">
  fifth item
</label>
```